# Windows Phone in-app products

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I've started creating a C# Windows Phone (Silverlight) app. I would really like to include in-app products. I've followed the tutorial: [Tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Increase_your_revenue_with_In-App_Purchase_on_Windows_Phone_8)

I've managed to add all the in-app products to my app. Just to test it, I've added a free in-app product. But when I click the download button in my app, I get an error message. My code is exactly the same as the above tutorial at the moment. I will change the code after fixing this error.

**Error message**
Service not available
The Store isn't available at the moment.
Please check back in a bit.
Inquiring minds may find this error code helpful: 805a01f4

I've googled the error code. According to the Microsoft website, I have to try again later. I've been trying for 3 days. But I am able to download apps from the store.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: if you can use the control. its because of unregistered or trail version.

Comment: @gayan1991. It's not a trail version. I've published the app, but it's hidden from the store at the moment. What do you mean by unregistered?

Comment: It could be because of subscription fees..... that they have not managed to do that so they have been signed off.

Comment: @HenryJooste Did you resolve this issue? I have the same error. Can it be the problem that you are trying to access product in one store from another store (for example access USA store from France)? Or it doesn't matter for beta apps?

Answer (score 0):

some people solved the problem by changing the APP-ID in the AppManifest.xml and WMAppManifest.xml to the one given in the dashboard.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/de-de/79e81def-39f4-4465-abad-d4c484f099ef/users-reporting-error-code-805a01f4-when-trying-to-buy-inapp-purchase?forum=wpdevelop

For me this solution didn't work, but maybe for you?